# how to get /log fS usage in two remote servers

Tags: ssh, filesystems, logs, disk-usage

how to trigger mail with below format by getting df -h /log fS usage

server1 | server 2

75%       |  50%

Below are step how i check FS usage manually

login to putty

ssh server1

give the password

issue command  df -h /log to get FS usage .

How do it get details from two servers server 1 ans server 2 and send  the FS

usage details in mail in below format

server1 | server 2

75%     |  50%

Comment: do you want to do this in a batch script that you run from the windows command line?  or do you want it to run automatically?  if the former, then your question is off-topic because it's about windows batch files.  if the latter, then set up cron jobs on the remote systems to run `df -h /log | mail -s "$(hostname -s): df -h /log" you@your.mail.host`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to remove the requirement to use a password to log into your servers.  Use public key based logins instead.  Once you've don that, you'll need something like:

```
$ for host in "server1" "server2" ; do echo $host; ssh $host df --output="ipcent" /tmp | tail -n1 | tr -d " "; done | pr --columns=2  --length=2 | mail bloggs@example.com
```

should work.

The line loops through both `server1` and `server2` and runs the command:

```
echo $host; ssh $host df --output="ipcent" /tmp
```

on each server in turn.  The output of this is simply the server name (`$host`) followed by the percentage use of the drive containing `/tmp`, but it has a header, so that is removed by piping it to:

```
tail -n1
```

which returns the last line (the percentage).  Unfortunately, that is surrounded by whitespace, so that is removed by piping it to:

```
tr -d " "
```

At this point, both servers would have been `ssh`'d, but the output would be something like:

```
server1
75%
server2
50%
```

so it is piped into:

```
pr --columns=2 --length=2
```

in order to rotate it to the format you requested:

```
server1     server2
75%         50%
```

Finally, this is piped into:

```
mail bloggs@example.com
```

to email it to `bloggs`.